# Отправить html письмо

Tags: php, header, sendmail

Я отправляю html письмо с картинкой.

Вот такие заголовки отправляю серверу

```
"From: =?utf-8?b?R2xvYmFsIERlbnQ=?= 
X-Mailer: zm php script
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="dentsend.ru-2018"
"
```

Вот так выглядит тело письма

```
"--dentsend.ru-2018
Content-type: multipart/related;
 boundary="dentsend.ru-2018-1"
--dentsend.ru-2018-1
Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
--dentsend.ru-2018-1
Content-Type: image/jpg
 name="file.2.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-ID: 
Content-Disposition: inline
 filename="file.2.jpg"
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... дальше бинарник очень длинный

--dentsend.ru-2018--
"
```

Письмо приходит, но картинки в теле письма нет вообще, а во вложение файл непонятного расширения с именем no_name.

В чём здесь ошибка? как это пофиксить?

Comment: А чем вам PHPMailer не угодил?

Comment: @Дмитрий здесь есть необходимость отправлять функцией mail()

Comment: просто обычно если необходимо отправлять файлы и не писать велосипеды лучше всего использовать готовые решения. А так да у Вас будет много головной боли

Comment: @Дмитрий да я согласен, только вопрос другой. Мне нужно это сделать с помощью mail(), и в чём тут велосипед, я просто либо в заголовках сделал ошибку либо в теле письма

Comment: Велосипед в том, что функция mail() по умолчанию не поддерживает отправку файлов

Comment: @Дмитрий да бог с ним, как это сделать то?.

Comment: текст большой я в ответе написал

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант примерно так:

```
$subject = "тема письма"; 

$message ="Текст сообщения"; 
// текст сообщения, здесь вы можете вставлять таблицы, рисунки, заголовки, оформление цветом и т.п.

$filename = "file.doc";
// название файла

$filepath = "files/file.doc";
// месторасположение файла


//исьмо с вложением состоит из нескольких частей, которые разделяются разделителем

$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); 
// генерируем разделитель

$mailheaders = "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\n"; 
$mailheaders .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n"; 
// разделитель указывается в заголовке в параметре boundary 

$mailheaders .= "From: $user_email <$user_email>\r\n"; 
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $user_email\r\n"; 

$multipart = "--$boundary\r\n"; 
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\r\n";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";    
$multipart .= \r\n;
$multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode(iconv("utf8", "windows-1251", $message)));
// первая часть само сообщение

// Закачиваем файл 
    $fp = fopen($filepath,"r"); 
        if (!$fp) 
        { 
            print "Не удается открыть файл22"; 
            exit(); 
        } 
$file = fread($fp, filesize($filepath)); 
fclose($fp); 
// чтение файла


$message_part = "\r\n--$boundary\r\n"; 
$message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\"\r\n";  
$message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
$message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n"; 
$message_part .= \r\n;
$message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
$message_part .= "\r\n--$boundary--\r\n";
// второй частью прикрепляем файл, можно прикрепить два и более файла

$multipart .= $message_part;

mail($to,$subject,$multipart,$mailheaders);
// отправляем письмо 

//удаляем файлы через 60 сек.
if (time_nanosleep(5, 0)) {
        unlink($filepath);
}
// удаление файла
```